# How to have fluid movements between server and client?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I'm creating a multiplayer game and I run into an issue with the movement of my character and actors.

When I test it in the editor there are no problems but when I package the game and test the multiplayer on two different computer, the client's side character movement is stuttering. It also happens on every actors like projectiles.

I guess the reason of this is that the server is correcting the position of actors but I don't know why positions are not correct in the first place.

to move my character, I use the "add Input Vector" function from character movement component and for my projectiles I use the "set Actor Location" in the Tick event.

Any advice ?
[Stuttering Movement on Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su3Mv.gif)